# JS Promise <Pending> returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, es6-promise

I'm currently struggling with returning a value from a chained event resulting in a Promise returned in a pending state.

My code returns an array of metafield objects for a specific Shopify product, which I then parse and would like to return an integer value.

However when I debug my code all I'm getting is a promise in a pending state rather than an executed value which is in scope to use.

I'm guessing this is largely down to my unfamiliarity with promises.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
var quantity = shopify.metafield.list({
  metafield: { owner_resource: 'product', owner_id: line_item.product_id }
}).then(metafields => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 

    //simplified code   
    resolve(2);
}))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Code needs elaboration

Comment: Yes of course `quanitity` is a promise. You cannot immediately get an integer that will only be created in the future. Just use `then` on your promise where you need to use the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopify.metafield.list({
  metafield: { owner_resource: 'product', owner_id: line_item.product_id }
}).then(metafields => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 

    //simplified code   
    resolve(2);
})).then((quantity)=> console.log(quantity))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

2nd .then() function is returning a new promise so you need to chain .then() function again in order to get the exact value returned from the promise(resolve)

Other way is to just use .then() function on quantity variable which contains promise returned by 2nd .then() function

```
quantity.then((res)=> console.log(res))
```

Comment: How do I assign the result of the quantity.then call to another object property? Using the code all I get is it outputing to console...I need this to be assigned to another object property.